# Create new sheet and then return to last active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Quick question!

I have a macro that uses Application.AciveSheet to reference the current worksheet since I want it to run in any of our numerous worksheets. It copies data from Application.ActiveSheet to another sheet "Labels". I would like to actually create the sheet labels in the macro and then return to Application.AciveSheet so that the rest of the macro can run. I can't because "Labels" becomes the new active sheet.

Here's my current script for reference

```
Sub LabelCreation()

'uses the active sheet and Z range to 120

lr = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("Z120").End(xlUp).Row
k = 0
For i = 4 To lr
k = k + 1

Application.ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & i).Copy
Sheets("Labels").Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Labels").Range("B" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("B" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Labels").Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Labels").Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

k = k + 1

Application.ActiveSheet.Range("AA" & i).Copy
Sheets("Labels").Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Labels").Range("B" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("B" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Labels").Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Labels").Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Labels").Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Use thisworkbook.activesheet to return

Comment: So after the macro creates the sheet "labels" I can just use thisworkbook.activesheet to return to my previous activesheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this code at the beginning of your code (1st line after Sub)

```
Sub LabelCreation()
    Set aws = ActiveSheet 'aws is current active sheet
    Sheets.Add 'add a new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Labels" 'name it "labels"
    aws.Activate 'reactivate initial active sheet
    'uses the active sheet and Z range to 120
```

Answer (score 3):

Would add a small tweak to the existing good answer to check that the *labels* sheet doesn't already exist (ie stop code running more than once)

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = Sheets.Add
On Error Resume Next
Set ws3 = Sheets("labels")
On Error GoTo 0
If ws3 Is Nothing Then
    ws2.Name = "labels"
Else
    MsgBox "sheet name already exists", vbCritical
End If
Application.Goto ws1.[a1]
```

Comment: Nice thank you, I have something similar set up like that where it checks if the worksheet Labels exists and deletes and then recreates it. The sheet is essentially used as a deposit to copy and paste from into a word document so I don't need it to permanently retain the data. But that's really handy to know how you scripted that.